# REACT - Accessing state with in useEffect callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, web-frontend

I've made an example of my question. I'm building a simple component that should manage the size of its children, but before any manipulation, needs to know the children's initial size.

So every child reports its own size on `useEffect` to the parent component, and parent component must keep the widths of all children, but only keeps the last one.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fdqv7x?file=index.tsx

the question is **Why the value of `widths` is empty on line no: 26?**

Comment: You want to get the old value when you set the state `setWidths(w => ({ ...w, [index]: width }));` demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kzgjfv?file=index.tsx

Comment: thanks @coglialoro, this could be real answer, I'm new to react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling `setWidths` you want to pass a callback that gets the latest state value, like this:

```
setWidths((w) => ({ ...w, [index]: width }));
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kzgjfv?file=index.tsx